# Express Routing middleware not working

Tags: node.js, express, routes, passport-local

I am trying to setup authentication of my MEAN stack using this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local.
I have setup passport to handle the authentication, but I have having toruble with the express routing.

I have routes set up for login, signup and logout:

```
// =====================================
    // LOGIN ===============================
    // =====================================
    // show the login form
    app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

        // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
        res.render('../public/login.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
    });

    // process the login form
    app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
       successRedirect : '/#home', // redirect to the secure profile section
       failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
       failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    }));

    // =====================================
    // SIGNUP ==============================
    // =====================================
    // show the signup form
    app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {

        // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
        res.render('signup.ejs', { message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
    });

    // process the signup form
   app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
       successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
       failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
       failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
   }));


// =====================================
// LOGOUT ==============================
// =====================================
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/login');
});
```

I have setup a route to a profile page that can only be accessed when the user is logged in:

```
// =====================================
    // PROFILE SECTION =====================
    // =====================================
    // we will want this protected so you have to be logged in to visit
    // we will use route middleware to verify this (the isLoggedIn function)
    app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('profile.ejs', {
            user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
        });
    });
```

This uses the following function as the middleware:

```
// route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/login');
}
```

The routing to the profile page works perfectly.
The problem is that I created a route that will catch all other requests to the site, and redirect the user to the login page if they are not logged in, like this:

```
app.get('*',  isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {

      res.render('../public/index.ejs', {
          user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
      });
    });
```

The catch all route does not work. If I make any other request, except to /profile, I can access the page without being logged in.

I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to get the catch all route to work! TIA!

Comment: Have you setup the passport middleware as well?

Comment: @Brennan not sure what you mean, but if the /profile route is working correctly doesnt this mean that the passport is setup correctly?

Comment: I only meant that you've followed the part of the tutorial [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local#application-setup-server-js) that initializes the passport stuff.  Specifically the session middleware.